# Virtual large document reading from XML file into a scroll control using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have legal documents that include 900 pages or more, which I need to read to an angularjs scroll control. Each paragraph of the document has a unique ID and I know how many paragraphs conform a section. A 900 hundred pages document can have as much as 2500 sections. I programmed to read blocks of 10 sections.

The problem is that I need to access sections and paragraphs randomly. A user can open a document and search a word, results are displayed in a vertical column to the left of the scroll control where any result can be clicked. If the user clicks a result, the control has to load the block that corresponds to the paragraph where the result is and show the paragraph at the top of the scroll control.

If then the user scrolls to see next pages the program knows when to read and everything is all right: the user can read some text while next blocks are being read, focused text is not moved. The problem is when the user wants to go backwards. If he scrolls towards the beginning of the document, as soon as the reading operation ends the control shows the first block read on this last reading operation.

This jump is not the desired behavior, I want a smooth reading operation that doesn’t jump from a text the user might be reading.

I found a tip on http://jsfiddle.net/MPsFC/1/ that uses `$content2.addClass('fixed');` so maybe a div tag with fixed position while text is being read is a solution. Any ideas?

Comment: this is a tremendously specific question, without some sample code it's very hard to give advice and solutions. Please update your question with the related code.

Comment: Also found a possible help on [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33777410/angularjs-ag-grid-sticky-remembered-selections-with-virtual-paging-infinite-s). This post uses an ag-grid.